# Syntax error in return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm getting a syntax error on the `return json_run(url, data)` line and I can't figure out why.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from json import loads as json_loads
import time
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import random

def json_run(url, data) :
        s = url + data
        try:
                r = urlopen(s)
                o = json_loads(r.read().decode('utf8'))
                return o
        except HTTPError as err:
                if err == 504:
                        # Retry
                        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10)
                        return json_run(url, data)
                else:
                        raise
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax error is (as it often is) on the line *before* the "offending" statement:

```
time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10)
```

is missing a closing parenthesis. And since it's legal to have linebreaks between parentheses, Python can only notice the problem on the following line.